# Rank Elasticsearch results by the shortest hit

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, n-gram

I am building a ngram search example with ES. Is is possible to take account the shortest length of all the hits?

Here's an example:

**Documents:**

- `{"aliases": ["ElonMuskTesla", "MuskTesla"]}`
- `{"aliases": ["ElonMusk"]}`

**Default Result:**
When searching for "Musk" against the field "aliases", the first document will have the highest score, because it has two hits matching "Musk".

**What I want:**
But I want the second document to appear on the top, because in my case, it's more relavant to the serach term (shortest means most similar).

---

I guess this might be achieved by the [script score query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-score-query.html), but don't know exactly how after browsing a bunch of seemingly related questions.

---

**[Appendix] Mapping & Settings:**

```json
{
   "settings":{
      "analysis":{
         "tokenizer":{
            "ngram":{
               "type":"ngram",
               "min_gram":2,
               "max_gram":40
            }
         },
         "analyzer":{
            "ngram_analyzer":{
               "tokenizer":"ngram",
               "filter":[
                  "lowercase"
               ]
            },
            "lower_analyzer":{
               "tokenizer":"keyword",
               "filter":[
                  "lowercase"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings":{
      "properties":{
         "aliases":{
            "type":"text",
            "analyzer":"ngram_analyzer",
            "term_vector":"with_positions_offsets",
            "search_analyzer":"lower_analyzer"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: please provide more details about your document. would be great if you share your document mapping details. is aliases field an array object?